# Drop Down Menu Disappears When Clicked After Being Scrolled

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu which follows as you scroll when your screen is under 930px.  It works great until you scroll.  You scroll and it stays up top but after you scroll and click the drop down menu, the drop down menu disappears.  Any ideas?

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FFFCYA8T8LZZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've scrolled down, your `#myTopnav` has `class="topnav active"`. Your click handler is this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

If you click after having scrolled down, the element's class is not equal to `topnav` (because it's `topnav active`), and thus this function sets the class back to `topnav`, removing the `active` class in the process.

Since you have jQuery in the page anyway, you can use its `toggleClass` method:

```
function myFunction() {
    $("#myTopnav").toggleClass("responsive");
}
```

This ensures that the `responsive` class and the `active` class are changed independently of each other.

Comment: Works perfectly thank you so much :-) https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FFFGWSKM6TDZ

Answer (score 0):

The active class being removed when you click seems to be the issue.

Try this fix:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav active") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav active";
    }
}
```